# HttpExchange.getRemoteAddress() takes long time

Tags: java, http

I am creating server running on Java HttpServer class, everything works fine but I've noticed that call to `exchange.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getCanonicalHostName()` takes about 4000 ms, however reading request body is fast even if I remove getRemoteAddress(). Does anyone know why HttpExchange.getRemoteAddress() takes so long time?
Log from server:

```
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:25:54] Received request from 192.168.0.104 / Obtaining remote address took 4538 ms
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:25:54] Downloading request body from 192.168.0.104 took 0 ms
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:25:54] Generating response body from 192.168.0.104 took 6 ms
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:25:54] Processing lock request from 192.168.0.104
```

Log when `exchange.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getCanonicalHostName()` is replaced with hardcoded string ("test"):

```
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:28:00] Received request from test / Obtaining remote address took 0 ms
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:28:00] Downloading request body from test took 1 ms
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:28:00] Generating response body from test took 7 ms
[pool-1-thread-1 | 13:28:00] Processing lock request from test
```

EDIT:
My failure, didn't read `getCanonicalHostName()` documentation properly. It clearly says

> Gets the fully qualified domain name for this IP address. Best effort
>   method, meaning we may not be able to return the FQDN depending on the
>   underlying system configuration.

replaced with `getHostAddress()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because finding hostname for the given IP address will typically involve a [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup), i.e. network query (or a series of queries) which is an expensive operation and naturally much slower than using a hard-coded string value.